# Express-handlebars not filling out {{{body}}}

Tags: express-handlebars

Using express-handlebars@5.2.0 and express@4.17.1 using node on windows and still cant get it to render in the body:

```
File Setup:

testapp.js
[views]
main.handlebars
[views][layouts]
test.handlebars
```

```
//testapp.js

    const express = require('express');
    const exhbr = require('express-handlebars');
    const app = express();
    const port = 3031;

    app.engine('handlebars', exhbr({}));
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('main', { layout: 'test' });
    });
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`));
```

```
<!--test.handlebars-->

<h1>Test</h1>
```

```
<!-- main.handlebars -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

Only `<h1>Test</h1>` is returned and hasn't been inserted into the body.

I have also tried the following just to make sure its looking in the right spots.

```
res.render('doesnt_exist');
Error: Failed to lookup view "doesnt_exist" in views directory "c:\wamp\www\rethinkdb_rest\views\"

res.render('main', { layout: "doesnt_exist" });
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\wamp\www\rethinkdb_rest\views\layouts\doesnt_exist.handlebars'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was putting the `main.handlebars` and `test.handlebars` in the wrong directories.

```
File Setup should be:

testapp.js
[views]
test.handlebars
[views][layouts]
main.handlebars
```

And the render function in `testapp.js` should be:

```
//testapp.js

    const express = require('express');
    const exhbr = require('express-handlebars');
    const app = express();
    const port = 3031;

    app.engine('handlebars', exhbr({}));
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('test', { layout: 'main' });     //<----fixed
    });
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`));
```